# Invalid `prisma.profile.findUnique()` invocation: Inconsistent column data: Malformed ObjectID: invalid character 'u' was found at index 0

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

This is a nextjs project with prisma , mongodb ...etc

This is my prisma.schema file :

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Profile {
  id       String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId   String @unique @db.ObjectId
  name     String
  imageUrl String @db.String
  email    String @db.String

  servers Server[]
  member  Member[]
  channels Channel[]

   
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Server {
  id         String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name       String
  imageUrl   String @db.String
  inviteCode String @db.String

  profileId String  @db.ObjectId
  profile   Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], onDelete: Cascade, references: [id])

  members Member[]
  channels Channel[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([profileId])
}

enum MemberRole {
  ADMIN
  MODERATOR
  GUEST
}

model Member {
  id   String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  role MemberRole @default(GUEST)

  profileId String  @db.ObjectId
  profile   Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], onDelete: Cascade, references: [id])

  serverId String @db.ObjectId
  server Server @relation(fields: [serverId], references: [id], onDelete:Cascade)

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([profileId])
  @@index([serverId])
}

enum ChannelType {
  TEXT
  AUDIO
  VIDEO
}

model Channel{
  id   String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name String
  type ChannelType @default(TEXT)

  profileId String  @db.ObjectId
  profile   Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], onDelete: Cascade, references: [id])

  serverId String @db.ObjectId
  server Server @relation(fields: [serverId], references: [id], onDelete:Cascade)


  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([profileId])
  @@index([serverId])
}
```

This is my (setup)/page.tsx

My SetupPage looks well-structured and makes good use of the initialProfile function to handle user authentication and profile initialization. Here are it's :

```
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { initialProfile } from "@/lib/initial-profile";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
const SetupPage = async () => {

    const profile = await initialProfile()

    const server = await db.server.findFirst({
        where:{
            members:{
                some:{
                    profileId: profile.id
                }
            }
        } 
    });

    if (server) {
        return redirect(`/servers/${server.id}`)
    }

    return ( 
        <div>
            Create a server
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default SetupPage;
```

This is my lib/initial-profile. I want to create a user profile each time a user sign up if the profile doesn't exist:

```
import { currentUser, redirectToSignIn } from "@clerk/nextjs";

import { db } from "@/lib/db";

export const initialProfile = async () => {

    const user = await currentUser();

    if (!user) {
        return redirectToSignIn()
    }

    const profile = await db.profile.findUnique({
        where: {
            userId: user.id
        }
    });

    if (profile) {
        return profile;
    }

    const newProfile = await db.profile.create({
        data: {
            userId: user.id,
            name: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`,
            imageUrl: user.imageUrl,
            email:user.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress
        }
    }) 

    return newProfile;

}
```

Question : is how to get a the existing profile. And How am I going to get ride of this error Unhandled Runtime Error
Error:
Invalid `prisma.profile.findUnique()` invocation:

Inconsistent column data: Malformed ObjectID: invalid character 'u' was found at index 0 in the provided hex string: "user_2Z2VbLwDcFw3TAEF4PmM4bj911S".`

Question : is how to get a the existing profile. And How am I going to get ride of this error Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Invalid `prisma.profile.findUnique()` invocation: Inconsistent column data: Malformed ObjectID: invalid character 'u' was found at index 0 in the provided hex string: "user_2Z2VbLwDcFw3TAEF4PmM4bj911S".`

I try this But its keeps on giving me the same error.

#### Added Validation for ObjectID Format:

The isValidObjectId variable uses a regular expression to check if user.id is a valid MongoDB ObjectID. If it's not valid, an error is logged, and you can handle it appropriately.

#### Improved Error Handling:

If the user.id is not a valid ObjectID, an error message is logged, and null is returned. You can customize the error handling based on your application's requirements.
By incorporating these changes, you can ensure that the user.id used in the query is in the correct format, reducing the likelihood of the "Malformed ObjectID" error. Additionally, it provides better insights into potential issues during development.

Comment: "user_2Z2VbLwDcFw3TAEF4PmM4bj911S" is not an ObjectId, if you want to use that as the _id field, change the schema so it doesn't expect an ObjectId.

Comment: and how am I going to do that please. can you show me

Comment: I'm getting the same error please any help @Joe

Comment: @Joe clarification please

Comment: Not really sure about Prisma types, try changing `@db.ObjectId` to `@db.String`

Answer (score 0):

- You should need to change schema as inside Profile model here:

> userId   String @unique @db.ObjectId

Change this to:

> userId   String @unique

make userId just string not ObjectId